# How do I dictate the destination folder of a clickOnce application?

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, clickonce

How do I dictate the destination folder of a clickOnce application?

Comment: Are you talking about the publish location for the setup program or where the program gets installed?

Comment: sorry, where the program gets installed or at least the data folder

Comment: What is your reason for needing a different directory?  I'm running into a situation where a security system is blocking executables from the application data folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible with ClickOnce. ClickOnce applications are always installed in the `Apps` subdirectory of local application data.

Answer (score 2):

As a further to the above, this is a security feature. Allowing websites to install software to arbitrary locations on someone's harddrive somewhat automatically is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

One Click application directly installs into the user profile directory. There is no way you can install it to your Programme files. To customize the your application use Installaware Admin http://www.installaware.com/studio-admin-features.htm