# How to allow installation in a custom target directory and suppress auto-start

Tags: vb.net, console, publish

I've developed a VB.NET console application and tried to use the Build | Publish menu option in Visual Studio 2008 to create a Setup. It works fine except two things:
- when I run the Setup on a Windows 2003 Server, it installs the application in the C:\Winnt\profiles\\Local Settings\Apps\2.0 directory. How can I configure the setup so that it would prompt for a target directory for the application?
- after the Setup is complete, it starts the application automatically. How can I suppress the auto-start?

Answer (score 2):

There are [two options to deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/e2444w33(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) VB.NET applications:

- [*ClickOnce*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN): This is what you are currently doing with Build | Publish. It always installs into the user's profile directory and it provides very little customization options.
- [*Windows Installer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2kt85ked(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN): This is what you create with File | New | Project | Other Project Types | Setup and Deployment | Setup Project. It allows full customization and installing to `Program Files`.

  **UPDATE**: Windows Installer Setup projects have been [removed in Visual Studio 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110002902/https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project), but are available as [an extension in Visual Studio 2013](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension/).

Letting the user choose a target directory is only possible with the latter option.

Related question: [How do I dictate the destination folder of a clickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145400/how-do-i-dictate-the-destination-folder-of-a-clickonce-application)

Comment: The second link, "Windows Installer", does not work for me. I'm unable to find ISLE anywhere in the project templates.

Comment: @Brady: Setup projects have been [removed in Visual Studio 2012](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project), but are available as [an extension in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx).