# Set click once technology installation path programmatically

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dictate the destination folder of a clickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145400/how-do-i-dictate-the-destination-folder-of-a-clickonce-application)

I am working on windows application in 4.0 version and I want to install click once technology remotely. How can I change the installation location path before installation by giving desired path. Is it possible to set the installation path programmatically and install click once technology remotely.

I know that,it is installed in the Application Cache, but is there some other way that we can install in another system's application cache, buy giving some input about the other systems name or path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. However, you cannot change where a ClickOnce application is installed. If you need it installed to a different location, you'll need to use something other than ClickOnce.