# Define install folder on client ClickOnce

Tags: .net, clickonce

When clients install Click Once published program, it installs to clients'  Appdata folder such as `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\{ID here}`

In every update it creates new folder named by NEW id..

How do set destination folder static for every update

Comment: I want to ask how to do when updating it should install to the same folder not to NEWID named folder. This is not duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

As noted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145400/how-do-i-dictate-the-destination-folder-of-a-clickonce-application) this is not possible with ClickOnce.

It is installed in the Application Cache and there is no way you can install it to some other folder directly by using ClickOnce.

Comment: What about publish to the same folder in every update